# Removing padding from box-sizing adds width to div

Tags: css, grid, padding

I'm using box-sizing content-box in a grid with 15px padding right. When I apply a padding of 0 to the last div the last div then gains 15px in width and the other divs in the row then lose an equal share of that 15px.

Is there any way fix this?

```
<div>
    <div class="col one_quarter">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col one_quarter">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col one_quarter">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col one_quarter last">
    <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
</div>

.col {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;

    border-right: 15px solid transparent;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.one_quarter { 
    width: 25%;
}

.col.last{
border-right-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're making your grid you have to take padding into consideration or you get some goofy results.

Also classes need to redistributed. (.col and .one_quarter are on the same elements. So you're 100% width and 25% width are overwriting each other)

[**Here's an Example Fiddle of what I did.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/aTbGL/)

Taking this into consideration I've updated your HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="one_quarter marginRight">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="one_quarter marginCenter">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="one_quarter marginCenter">
        <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="one_quarter marginLeft">
    <h5>One Quarter</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col {
    width: 100%;
}

.one_quarter { 
    width: 23%;
    float: left;
    border:1px dotted red;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col.last{
border-right-width: 0;
}

.marginCenter{margin-right:1%;margin-left:1%;}
.marginLeft{margin-left:2%;}
.marginRight{margin-right:2%;}
```

Comment: This is apart of a much larger grid so the .col class is for other columns. I should have also said that I'm creating a fluid grid with fixed gutters, would what you suggest work with px?

Comment: It could work with pixels as long as you the percentages + pixels don't go over 100% of the width of whatever container you're using. If you resize this fiddle width size you can see the issue.
http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/aTbGL/2/

Comment: Hmmm, the only solution I can think of is having padding left and right and then increase the container width but then I wouldn't be able to have nested grids.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend not placing padding your your grid elements. This can lead to major headaches down the road.

Add another div and apply your padding inside your grid cell like this:

```
<div class="grid">
   <div class="grid-cell">
      <div class="grid-content">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

.grid-content {
 padding: 15px;
}
```

Let the grid-cells do the width measurements, and the grid-contents do the padding.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with content so far but I'll keep that in mind.